# Webpack "cannot get" when i refresh on subpage

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

So i am buiding an E-Learning app.

Now yesterday i manually configured webpack

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', {
                "targets": "defaults" 
              }],
              '@babel/preset-react'
            ]
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
    }),
  ],
  externals: {
    "pdfjs-dist": "pdfjsLib",
    "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js": "pdfjsWorker"
  }
}
```

The extarnals thing is to show a custom PDF viewer.

Now in my package.json i have this

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --hot",
    "build": "webpack",
```

And it works great, the build is great and de development too. but i have a problem.

When i am on a screen link and refresh it shows: "http://localhost:8080/mijn-account"
it gives the error "Cannot GET /mijn-account"

So then i need to go back to "http://localhost:8080/" and then click on the button which goes to "http://localhost:8080/mijn-account" and then i see the change. but it costs so much time. What do i need to do?

I already tried some things with hot reloud but i don't get it and when i save the "mijn-account" file it refreshes automatically so thats nice but how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your route dont work in production build? If so the problem is not in webpack but in settings of your server. You need to configure your server to redirect all pages to index.html instead of `/something.html`.

nginx example:

```
  location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

Comment: So the production build is fine. The developers build is not good.

Comment: then you need to set api fallback to index.html for webpack. [Here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) is documentation. Just set `historyApiFallback: true`

Comment: It will redirect any route that is not found to index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that any MUI component being used in the project which contains `href='/'` tag inside `<TextLink href="{Link}" />`.
instead try to use useNavigate hook to redirect the link, with the `historyApiFallback:true` inside devServer under webpack.
this might solve the issue
thank you